# If every file is associated with a inode number, then how to distinguish file a between file b that with the same inode number?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Say partition A mounted on /, partition B mounted on /opt, then dir / and /opt will have the same inode number 2.

So my question is, when i'm in / and want `cd /opt`, how does it know that the inode number of /opt is belongs to partition B not A?

I read this [article](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/13w/notes/450_file_system.html#tracing-inodes-in-pathnames) about how traverse the directory tree in one filesystem. I wonder how traverse directory tree across different filesystems.